# In a HTML-tag style"{...}{:active ... } doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, button

I stuck, because I tried so many different combinations, I have no idea why this doesn't work.

Wordpress
woocommerce 
Checkout
From (submit) back button
form submit button tag with `style="{} :active{}"`

I have no head where I can store css, just a template with the form.
Submit is already pre styled in the main style.css. 
I just wanna style two buttons "Pay" and "back", not all buttons.
I put the complete css in the html of the button, this is working exept the :active this doesn't work

```
<table width="100%"><tr><td width="23%"><input type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_update_totals" id="place_order" value="<?php _e( 'back', Woocommerce_German_Market::get_textdomain() ) ?>" style="{position: relative;color: rgba(255,255,255,1);text-decoration: none;background-color: rgb(248, 1, 8);font-weight: bold;display: block;padding: 18px;-webkit-border-radius: 8px;-moz-border-radius: 8px;border-radius: 8px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgb(179, 6, 1), 0px 9px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7);-moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgb(179, 6, 1), 0px 9px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7);box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgb(179, 6, 1), 0px 9px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7);margin: 2px 0px 25px 0px;text-align: center;-webkit-transition: all .1s ease;-moz-transition: all .1s ease;-ms-transition: all .1s ease;-o-transition: all .1s ease;transition: all .1s ease; font-size: 1.387em;} :active {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgb(179, 6, 1), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.9);-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgb(179, 6, 1), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.9);box-shadow:0px 3px 0px rgb(179, 6, 1), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.9);position: relative;top: 6px}" /></td>
<td width="77%"><div align="center">something maybe a button</div></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax in your `style` attribute is incorrect.

Use `style="property: value; ..."` instead of `style="{}"`

Therefore in your case, it would be:

```
<div style="width:50px; height:50px; background:blue;"></div>
```

I'd suggest avoiding all that inline styling an moving that logic into a stylesheet instead:

```
.active {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: OK but I just wanna style one button. input and submit are already styled. I wanna override this especialy for the checkout button(s) in the checkout template. I have no head-Tag only the form

Comment: @Marco-SiegfriedPenthin Then you need to be more specific with the styling, see my update. I use `.button` instead.

Comment: Hey Josh, THANK YOU SO MUCH!! WORKING!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The style attribute should contain only CSS declarations. It should not include the `{}` that goes around them in a stylesheet.

There is no way to include selectors in a style attribute, you need to use a regular stylesheet for that.

Comment: Ok but how I implement the :active to visualize the button pressed?

Comment: You use a style sheet (via `<link>` or `<style>`) and not a style attribute.

Comment: edit button styles in `.button {
  color: red;
}
.button:active {
  color: green;
}`

Answer (score 0):

in the header add

```
<style type='text/css'>
input :active {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgb(179, 6, 1);
//... what ever you have put for active 
}
</style>
```

Try.

Comment: OK but I just wanna style one button. input and submit are already styled. I wanna override this especialy for the checkout button(s) in the checkout template. I have no head-Tag only the form

Comment: use .class name I just generalized it :)

Comment: Thanks Anobik form your help